# Resize/position canvas in a custom SurfaceView (Android)

Tags: android, surfaceview, android-canvas

I'll try to short my question:

I'm trying to make a little game and got a class inheriting SurfaceView, and also a class with a Thread which will handle the SurfaceView's Holder.
In the thread loop I lock the Canvas I get from the Holder and the I call the methods update() and draw() inside the SurfaceView class.
The canvas represents everything on the screen. Now that's my question:
Is there any way to resize the canvas (maybe using Matrices as we do with Bitmaps) and then position it?

If you ever wanna know why, it's because the "target screen" I'm working has to be of a specific ratio, so, depending on the actual screen size I would have to resize the canvas and reposition it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I just had to apply the matrix to scale and translate to the entire canvas.